# checkbox count on another frame

Tags: javascript, html

I have 10 checkboxes inside a frame within a frameset of 3.

```
<frameset cols="16%,68%,16%">
    <frame src="fish.html" name="bodyleft" noresize scrolling=no>
    <frame src="fish1.html" name="bodymid" noresize scrolling=no>
    <frame src="fish2.html" name="bodyright" noresize scrolling=no>
    </frameset>
```

code on fish1.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function countCheckboxes ( ) 
  {
    var form = document.getElementById('testForm');
    var count = 0;
    for(var n=0;n < form.length;n++)
    {
      if(form[n].name == 'items[]' && form[n].checked)
      {
        count++;
      }
    }
    document.getElementById('checkCount').innerHTML = count;
  }
  window.onload = countCheckboxes;
</script>
```

Is it possible to count the number of checked checkboxes on fish2.html, not on fish1? How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (have not tested):

```
var frame2 = document.getElementById('bodyright');
window.onload = countCheckboxes(frame2);
function countCheckboxes (frame) 
{
   var forms = frame.document.getElementsByTagName('form');
   //...
}
```

Comment: @user2135437 your code is very unclear. You are getting element with id and then iterating it in for (getElementById returns 1 element only) and this element as i guessed is not form, it's checkbox